# Infragistics ASP.NET WebMenu Styling?

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, infragistics

Can anyone please recommend a company who styles Infragistics for ASP.NET controls? Is there even a company who does that?

A friend needs to style a webmenu like a sample css menu and neither he or I are that good at CSS to get it 100% right.

If anyone knows who might be able to do this, please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Infragistics Support team if you have a subscription, otherwise the forums are pretty good at getting things resolved...

WebMenu Forum:
http://news.infragistics.com/forums/116.aspx